# What is the purpose of putting a " \ " before a tuple?

Tags: python-3.x

```
patterns = \ 

    (
    ('[sxz]$', '$', 'es'),
    ('[^aeioudgkprt]h$', '$', 'es'),
    ('(qu|[^aeiou])y$', 'y$', 'ies'),
    ('$', '$', 's') 
    )
```

I found this example in a python book. Unfortunately, the author did not give any explanation about how the backlash works here. I failed to find any document related to it in google. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 3):

it's line continuation, and it's largely unnecessary if you structure your style guide correctly. For example the above could be written:

```
patterns = ( ('[sxz]$', '$', 'es'),
             ('[^aeioudgkprt]h$', '$', 'es'),
             ('(qu|[^aeiou])y$', 'y$', 'ies'),
             ('$', '$', 's') 
           )
```

And the \ would not be needed.

Comment: In other words, it's got nothing to do with tuples, it's just a generic way to split something to multiple lines.

Comment: I personally would put one open paren `(` on the first line and then one item on each line, but this is a minor variant.  The last item, here `('$', '$', 's')` can have a comma `,` following.  This standard trick makes adding and deleting lines easier and results in smaller patch diffs.